Knocking sound when applying brakes, but does not happen reliably
I have a 2012 Toyota Rav4. There is a knocking sound that happens when the brakes are applied. The knocking sound occurs at a rate that matches the speed of the wheel rotation. As the speed slows, the knocking slows.
This has happened before and it was a warped rotor. The difference this time, is that it only happens rarely. This confuses me, because if it was a warped rotor, I assume the sound would happen all the time.
I am very confused as to why this would only happen once or twice a commute.
What are some diagnostics I could perform to get to the bottom of this?

It would be prudent to check that all your lug nuts are tight before you drive any more; having a wheel come off during your commute would kind of ruin your day and possibly someone else's too!

Good suggestion. They are tight.
